# Mapbox - Use gps location

Tags: android, gps, location, mapbox

I develop an Android app. 
I want to stock the gps location and draw a line on the map with these datas, like "draw my course".

What's the best way ?

I designed my map with TileMill.

Where can I stock my data and use it with mapbox?

---

This is my code :

```
public class GPSActivity extends Activity{
private LocationManager manager = null;
private MyLocationListener listener;
private TextView textView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.location);
    listener = new MyLocationListener(textView);


    manager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    listener = new MyLocationListener(textView);

    manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager
            .GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 10,listener);

    }
public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener
{
TextView textView;

public MyLocationListener(TextView textView)
{
    this.textView = textView;
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    this.textView.setText(location.toString());
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

}

}
```

--> With this code, I have the location. I would like to stock longitude and latitude and use these with mapbox. What's the best way to stock these datas? 
I start to design my map on map box : https://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/malicia.hh3dgalc/page.html?secure=1#13/48.1169/-1.6803
It will be an interactive map, I want to draw an itinerary with the datas stocked.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Please Show What have you tried till now.